# Add constraint to route to exclude certain keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails and I want to use contraint in route to exclude that route if keyword "incident" is anywhere in the url.

I am using rails3.

Here is my existing routes.

```
match ':arg', :to => "devices#show", :constraints => {:arg => /???/}
```

I need to put something in constraints so that it does not match if word "incident" is there.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
(?!.*?incident).*
```

might be what you want.

This is basically the same question as [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex). Go there for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of bending regular expressions a way it is not intended to, I suggest this approach instead:

```
class RouteConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    not request.params[:arg].include?('incident')
  end
end

Foo::Application.routes.draw do
  match ':arg', :to => "devices#show", :constraints => RouteConstraint.new
  ...
```

Its a lot more verbose, but in the end more elegant I think.

Comment: well, in some cases using another class to exclude a simple word seems overkill. in our case it helps the dev team to keep track of the routes we're excluding in the same file

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto @Johannes answer for rails 4.2.5:

config/routes.rb (at the VERY end)

```
constraints(RouteConstraint) do
  get "*anythingelse", to: "rewrites#page_rewrite_lookup"
end
```

config/initializers/route_constraint.rb

```
class RouteConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    not ["???", "Other", "Engine", "routes"].any? do |check|
      request.env["REQUEST_PATH"].include?(check)
    end
  end
end
```