# Regular expression for search query like: word1 * (word2 -word3 -word4) * word5

Tags: mysql, regex

The question is, what will be regular expression for search of words sequence excluding some words in concrete part of string?

For example, for search request:

`word1 * (word2 -word3 -word4) * word5`

(where `*` means any number of any words, and `-word` means excluding word)

Matched strings will be:

`word1 word99 word2 word98 word97 word5`

`word1 word2 word5`

Not matched:

`word1 word99 word2 word98 WORD4 word97 word5`

`word1 WORD3 word2 word5`

P.S. It's for search in MySQL using REGEXP operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex

Comment: @Joseph Silber It does not works in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do that with REGEXP, you should create a FULLTEXT index on your column and do [FULLTEXT searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), doing the searches [IN BOOLEAN MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) will give you all the features you want.

Comment: I can't use FULL TEXT search because MySQL tables are on InnoDB engine. And anyway using FULL TEXT is not issue because there are no some REGEXP features that I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Sphinx, it has required features.