# Regex for matching something if it is not preceded by something else

Tags: java, regex

With regex in Java, I want to write a regex that will match if and only if the pattern is not preceded by certain characters. For example:

```
String s = "foobar barbar beachbar crowbar bar ";
```

I want to match if `bar` is not preceded by `foo`. So the output would be:

```
barbar
beachbar
crowbar
bar
```

Answer (score 497, accepted):

You want to use `negative lookbehind` like this:

```
\w*(?<!foo)bar
```

Where `(?<!x)` means "only if it doesn't have "x" before this point".

See [Regular Expressions - Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more information.

**Edit**: added the `\w*` to capture the characters before (e.g. "beach").

Comment: what modifications need to be made to not match foo_arbitrary_bar?  ie foo not immediately preceding bar

Comment: @BradKent `(?<!foo).*bar` would match something like that, I believe.

Comment: @emyller nope.  that will match foobazbar  (foo doesn't come before foobazbar, so it matches)

Comment: @BradKent I didn't read your "not" in "not match", that why I said it would match. You case looks like a `\b(?!foo)\w*bar\b` to me then.

Comment: @emyller nope.  that will match bazfoobar

Comment: @BradKent Then you can either ask a new question, elaborating what you're trying to achieve in detail, or continue playing with regular expressions until you find it yourself. :)

Comment: What if I want to get all the numbers (or any other character/string) but the ones preceded by a given string: e.g.: `String s = "foo123 bar45 foo1 bar7"`. I'd like to get: 45 and 7.
This re doesn't work properly: `(?<!foo)\d+`

Comment: Thanks for this. However this only match the first instance. How do I match all instances of bar not proceeded by foo? I tried \w*(?<!foo)barg but of course that is not right. Sorry I am quite new to Regex.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to first match optional word characters followed by `bar`, and when that has matched check what is directly to the left is not `foobar`.

The lookbehind assertion will run after matching `bar` first.

```
\w*bar(?<!foobar)
```

- `\w*` Match 0+ word characters
- `bar` Match literally
- `(?<!foobar)` Negative lookbehind, assert from the current position `foobar` is not directly to the left.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Fhmlc/1)

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, it could be easier to optionally include the preceding part, then skip those matches in a second step. For instance, to find numbers that don't start with a "+":

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\+?[0-9][0-9\s\-].*[0-9])/s',$text,$matches)) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
        if(substr($match,0,1) == '+'){
            continue;
        }
        // continue processing
    }
}
```

The negative look behind did not work since it would still match 2+ digits, but it would not include the first digit in the match. For instance +1234 would be returned as 234.