# Match string not preceded by another with a regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

The statement

```
Regex.Replace("XB", "([^A])B", "$1AB")
```

produces `XAB`, as expected. Can someone explain me why

```
Regex.Replace("XBB", "([^A])B", "$1AB")
```

does **not** produce `XABAB`, but `XABB`? It's like the regex parser no longer has knownledge of the preceding character when it reaches the second B.

Ultimately, I want to replace all `B`s not preceded by a `A` by `AB`.

Comment: The answer you chose won't really work. For future reference, I'd wait a while for alternative answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for matching something if it is not preceded by something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All B's not preceded by a A by AB.**

Find: `(?<!A)B`
Replace: `AB`

Comment: That indeed looks good. It's simpler and more logical than the answer I accepted. Could you provide an example where @Avinash's solution fails while yours works?

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune: There is one difference between this and the other answer: This answer will replace `B` at the beginning of the string, while the other answer does not. You are not very clear what will happen in such case, though.

Comment: Indeed, I had to use `([^A]|^)(?=B)` to make it also work at the beginning of the string. Your solution is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: The pattern in this answer is handy for converting text with Unix newlines to text with DOS/Windows newlines, when adjusted as follows:  `(?<!\r)\n`

Comment: Be aware that even nowadays 2021 safari still not support lookbehind feature.

Comment: This works in JS([link]https://regexr.com/652sd[/link]) but not powershell. I am using `-replace` to remove the character. `-replace '(?<!")(`n)', ''`

Answer (score 3):

In a .NET regex flavor, you may use lookbehinds like this:

**Match `foo` not *immediately* preceded with `bar`**

```
(?<!bar)foo
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!bar%29foo&i=foo%20barfoo%20foo).

**Match `foo` not preceded with `bar` *anywhere in the string***

```
(?s)(?<!bar.*?)foo
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C!bar.*%3F%29foo&i=foo%20barfoo%20foo).

**Match `foo`  *immediately* preceded with `bar`**

```
(?<=bar)foo
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Dbar%29foo&i=foo%20barfoo%20foo).

**Match `foo` preceded with `bar` *anywhere in the string***

```
(?s)(?<=bar.*?)foo
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3Dbar.*%3F%29foo&i=foo%20barfoo%20foo).

The latter contains `.*?` in the negative lookbehind allowing the regex engine to check for `bar` and any zero or more chars immediately to the left of `foo`, so the `bar` does not have to come immediately before `foo`.

The `(?s)` inline modifier allows `.` to match any characters including newlines.

The current problem is easily solved by using a negative lookbehind (see the top scenario),

```
var result = Regex.Replace("XBB", "(?<!A)B", "AB");
```

Comment: I know the original answer is about .NET, but is there any way to achieve the `(?<!bar.*?)foo` behavior with PCRE without the **"lookbehind assertion is not fixed length"** error?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes, use `bar.*foo(*SKIP)(*F)|foo` or even `bar.*?foo.*(*SKIP)(*F)|foo`

Comment: Wow, a big thanks, didn't know about `(*SKIP)` or `(*F)` before. In case anyone looking for the same and meet the `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)` first time like me, you can find an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/7121513).

Comment: This works in JS(regexr.com/652sd) but not powershell. I am using `-replace` to replace the character. `-replace '(?<!")(n)', ''`. I am trying to remove new lines that occur after any character except `"`.  What is wrong in my command.

Comment: @hirani89 `(Get-Content $filepath -Raw) -replace '(?m)(?<=[^\r\n"])(?:\r\n?|\n)'`

Answer (score 1):

Note that this `([^A])B` regex matches the first `XB` and captures the `X` . Because the `B` following the `X` is already present in a match, so it won't be matched another time. In this case, i suggest you to use lookarounds.

```
([^A])(?=B)
```

`(?=B)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by the letter `B`.

But it produces `XABBABB` when the replacement string is `$1AB`. To get the desired output, just remove the `B` from the replacement string. That is replace the matched characters with `\1A`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rP1kU2/3)

Comment: I edited my question to clarify my goal. I want to get `XABAB`. With your suggestion, I get `XABBABB`.