# How to Make Maven Surefire Plugin Include Regex not Match a Specific Prefix?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to let maven-surefire-plugin only run all the tests fulfilling following conditions:

- Match the pattern `*Test.java`, but NOT `*SomeTest.java`;
- OR match the pattern `*AnotherSomeTest.java`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I've already tried the include string:

`**/*Test.java, !%regex[.*(?!Another)SomeTest.*]`

however this does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several solutions possible using [a regular expression](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html#Regular_Expression_Support). The simplest one is having the configuration

```
<includes>
  <include>*AnotherSomeTest.java</include>
  <include>%regex[.*(?&lt;!Some)Test\.class]</include>
</includes>
```

This will match tests where the class name ends either with `AnotherSomeTest`, or with `Test` [but not preceded by `Some`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else) (the negative lookbehind `<` just needs to be properly escaped with `&lt;`). Note that the regular expression match is done over the `.class` file, while the traditional one is done over the `.java` file.

You could put this into a single regular expression, with

```
<include>%regex[.*(?&lt;!(?&lt;!Another)Some)Test\.class]</include>
```

which selects all tests ending with `Test`, not preceded by `Some` themselves not preceded by `Another`, although it's probably not clearer.

Another alternative is to use [multiple formats into one](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html#Multiple_Formats_in_One), that works since version 2.19 of the plugin and JUnit 4 or TestNG. This is useful for the command line notably:

```
<include>%regex[.*(?&lt;!Some)Test\.class], *AnotherSomeTest.java</include>
```