# Replace character if not preceeded by "+"

Tags: java, regex, replace

in java i need to replace a number with a word only if it is not preceeded by the "+".
Example:

```
- match1
- match+1
```

Should become:

```
matchone
match+1 (no modify)
```

I tried with

```
>>>name = name.replaceAll("([^+])1", "one");
matcone                                      //required "matchone"
```

But it is not working. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Is the requirement to replace only number '1'? Your question does not specify but your regex suggests otherwise.

Comment: yes i need only to replace the "1"

Comment: You need to specify what you mean with "But it is not working". What is the output you're getting, and what is the output that you expected?

Comment: See [regex for matching something if it is not preceded by something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else).

Comment: for "not working" i mena it does not replace anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
name = name.replaceAll("(?<!\\+)1", "one");
```

Comment: You mean: "look-behind"

Comment: This gives an "Illegal escape character in string literal" :-(

Comment: @YCF_L: Thanks for edit. I always forget double escaping :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is eating the character before the one and replacing that with "one" as well, so the output in the first instance is "matcone".

You can use a negative look-behind expression (`?<!`) to match any "1" that is not preceded by a "+":

```
name = name.replaceAll("(?<!\\+)1", "one");
```