# Match if something is not preceded by something else

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to parse a string and extract some numbers from it. Basically, any 2-3 digits should be matched, except the ones that have "TEST" before them. Here are some examples:

```
TEST2XX_R_00.01.211_TEST => 00, 01, 211
TEST850_F_11.22.333_TEST => 11, 22, 333
TESTXXX_X_12.34.456      => 12, 34, 456
```

Here are some of the things I've tried:

`(?<!TEST)[0-9]{2,3}` - ignores only the first digit after TEST

`_[0-9]{2,3}|\.[0-9]{2,3}` - matches the numbers correctly, but matches the character before them (_ or .) as well.

I know this might be a duplicate to [regex for matching something if it is not preceded by something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else) but I could not get my answer there.

Comment: In the second case, Is it not possible for you to capture the required data within a group and fetch it from there? `[_.](\d{2,3})` [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/VKsXwg/1)

Comment: Lua does not support regex, only specific Lua patterns. You should tag these questions with `lua-patterns`, *unless* you are using an external regex engine. Are you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, I was experimenting in a browser

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Please restore the "regex" tag.  Searching for "lua" + "regex" is a usual practice to search for Lua pattern-related questions.  Actually, nobody (except you) expects that "lua-pattern" tag exists.  Tags on SO were introduced to help usual users, they are not for academically correct classification.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Ok, let's add `regex` back (since OP tests were made at regex101 and show original logic), but keep `lua-patterns`.

Comment: @PoVa - Try pattern `%f[T%d]%d+`, it matches every chain of digits not preceded by letter `T`, it may be what you need:  `local s = "TEST2XX_R_00.01.211_TEST"; for x in s:gmatch"%f[T%d]%d+" do print(x) end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to use a single pattern to match a string not preceded with some sequence in Lua (note that you can't even rely on capturing an alternative that you need since `TEST%d+|(%d+)` will not work in Lua, Lua patterns do not support alternation).

You may remove all substrings that start with `TEST` + digits after it, and then extract digit chunks:

```
local s = "TEST2XX_R_00.01.211_TEST"
for x in string.gmatch(s:gsub("TEST%d+",""), "%d+") do  
    print(x)
end
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/nFqrmU)

Here, `s:gsub("TEST%d+","")` will remove `TEST<digits>+` and `%d+` pattern used with `string.gmatch` will extract all digit chunks that remain.