# How to match for "foo" and "bar" with Select-String in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, text, read-eval-print-loop, select-string

How to [get the result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/4531180) of these `Select-String` matches in one statement?

```
posh> 
posh> $string = Get-Content /home/nicholas/powershell/regex/text.txt
posh> $patternFoo = 'foo'                                           
posh> $patternBar = 'bar'
posh> $string | Select-String $patternFoo -AllMatches | Select-String $patternBar -AllMatches

jfkldafdjlfoofkldasjf jfkdla jfklsadfj fklsdfjbarfjkdlafj

posh> 
posh> $string


fjdksalfoofjdklsafjdk fjdkslajfd fdjksalfj fjdkaslfdls

jfkldafdjlfoofkldasjf jfkdla jfklsadfj fklsdfjbarfjkdlafj

posh>
```

Looking to match "foo" and "bar" in a single [pattern](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/).

Comment: please, remove the meaningless prompt text from your posted code. it is both useless AND distracting.

Comment: That's just how the powershell prompt displays, not sure how to alter it @Lee_Dailey

Comment: @NicholasSaunders, just use `PS> ` to symbolize the prompt string - anything else is noise.

Comment: for anyone on linux, you can shorten the prompt as so:  https://askubuntu.com/q/1318242/847449

Comment: @NicholasSaunders - you use your text editor to remove prompt text ... [*grin*]

Comment: lol, @Lee_Dailey -- then I'd have to do that manually!  this way, it's just always "posh" (or whatever)

Comment: I changed the profile, so that the `pwd` isn't displayed @Lee_Dailey see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66309076/4531180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple positive lookahead assertions that each scan the entire input line (non-greedily):

```
'a bar foo ...' | Select-String '(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar)'
```

---

**Note**:

- This approach is also available as a *wrapper* function around [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), named `Select-StringAll`, in this **[MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/356acffc2521fdd338ef9d6daf41ef07)**.
- Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install it directly as follows:

  ```
  irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/356acffc2521fdd338ef9d6daf41ef07/raw/Select-StringAll.ps1 | iex
  ```

With this function defined, the equivalent of the above command is:

```
'a bar foo ...' | Select-StringAll foo, bar
```

Answer (score 0):

possible solution, or approach towards a solution:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $pattern = '\w*(?<!foo)bar'                  
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $string = Get-Content /home/nicholas/powershell/regex/text.txt
PS /home/nicholas> $pattern = '\w*(?<!foo)bar'                                   
PS /home/nicholas> $string | Select-String $pattern

jfkldafdjlfoofkldasjf jfkdla jfklsadfj fklsdfjbarfjkdlafj

PS /home/nicholas>
```

thanks to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9306228/4531180