# Regex for 10 or 6 digit number should not start and end with '/' and can also be a single word in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex

Need regex for 6 or 10 digit number can be start and end with space, can also be a single word in a whole string. It should not start and end with '/'.

For example:

1. `My Zip-code is 101010. Please update.` -> `101010`
2. `9090909090 is my mobile number` -> `9090909090`
3. `00/9090909090/000000/` -> should not find any number
4. `9090909090` -> `9090909090`

I have tried this

```js
\b(\d{11}|\d{10}|\d{6})\b
```

regex, but unable to handle 3rd situation.

Comment: So what have you tried to do?

Comment: \b(\d{11}|\d{10}|\d{6})\b

Comment: `\b` is not really matching the condition of "not starting or ending with `/`" as it matches zero-length characters (word boundaries)

Comment: @thinkgruen do you have any suggestion for the above problem statement

Comment: Yep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else. Additionally, you need a look-behind as well

Comment: No, it is not helpful in this case, as it does not answer the current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b\d{6}(?:\d{4})?\b(?!\/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AvnNwG/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb%5Cd%7B6%7D(%3F%3A%5Cd%7B4%7D)%3F%5Cb(%3F!%5C%2F)):

[image]

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d{6}` - any six digits
- `(?:\d{4})?` - an optional sequence of four digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\/)` - there must be no `/` immediately to the right of the current location (this is a negative lookahead).