# Regex fallback if multiple conditions were not met, fallback must not match any of previous conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating an IBAN checker that currently works fine: it recognizes the first 2 characters (e.g. DE or GB) and according to the matched country code checks the specific IBAN structure (DE is followed by numbers only, while GB has a some letters somewhere in there). So those things get checked perfectly fine.

Here the working code without a fallback: https://regex101.com/r/HqThjy/1

```
^(?:GB\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}|DE\d{20})$

this matches:
DE12312341212312312312
GB12ASDF12312312312311
```

But I want to integrate a fallback for when non of my set countries I want to check specifically (let's stick with DE and GB) are matched, for example Norway with its code **NO**. My current idea of a fallback ends my example with an ELSE condition but this matches also a false DE and GB string: https://regex101.com/r/HqThjy/3

```
^(?:GB\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}|DE\d{20})|[A-Z]{2}(?:[A-Z]|\d){13,}$

this matches:
DE12312341212312312312
GB12ASDF12312312312311
NO1212121212121
DE1231234121231 <- should not be a match
GB1231231231231 <- should not be a match
```

Is there maybe a way to tell regex, if it does not match "DE *or* GB" then check against anything, but not DE/GB?

Answer (score 2):

In case when using Javascript and a negative lookbehind is not supported, you can also turn the lookbehind in a lookahead, and change the last alternation to a character class

```
^(?:GB\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}|DE\d{20})|(?!DE|GB)[A-Z]{2}[A-Z\d]{13,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0AqeuY/1)

Answer (score 1):

While typing the question and preparing the examples I stumbled over this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else) which has the solution: `negative lookbehind`

I adapted my code to look like this: https://regex101.com/r/HqThjy/4

```
^(?:GB\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d{14}|DE\d{20})|[A-Z]{2}(?<!DE|GB)(?:[A-Z]|\d){13,}$
```

This `[A-Z]{2}(?<!DE|GB)` does the trick. It looks for 2 uppercase letters and only proceeds, if the preceding 2 characters are not **DE** or **GB**. More about **Lookbehind** here: [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind)