# awk add an escape character into a split command

Tags: bash, awk

I need to split a field in awk by a "+" character, but not if the character preceding it is a "?". I have put together a basic example of the idea below.

```
exampleString="Var1, Var2Pt1+Var2Pt2+Var2Pt?+3+Var2Pt4, Var3"

awkOutput=`awk '
BEGIN{FS=",";}
{NUM_PARTS=split($2,SUBFIELDS,"+");
    for (i = 1; i<=NUM_PARTS; i++) {
        print SUBFIELDS[i]","
    }
}
' <<<"$exampleString"`

echo $awkOutput;
```

Current Output:

```
Var2Pt1, Var2Pt2, Var2Pt?, 3, Var2Pt4,
```

Desired Output:

```
Var2Pt1, Var2Pt2, Var2Pt+3, Var2Pt4,
```

Is there some way to deal with this using split, or is there another means of achieving this in an elegant manner? The need for this has arisen in part of a very large awk script - so the simpler the solution the better!

Thanks.

Just an update - I did not make explicit that the "?" is to be treated as an escape character in my original question - i.e. it is not desired on the output.

Comment: Don't use all upper case for user-defined awk variables to avoid clashes with builtin variable names and so it's clear that your variables aren't built-in ones.

Comment: In the desired output, shouldn't it be `Var2Pt?+3` instead of `Var2Pt+3`?

Comment: _part of a very large awk script_ .... Which awk are you using? Wouldn't it make more sense to implement this in a language which as _negatie lookbehind regexes_, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306202/regex-for-matching-something-if-it-is-not-preceded-by-something-else#9306228), such as Python or Ruby?

Comment: @user1934428 no, the desired output should remove the escape character which has been set as "?". Regards uses of other scripting, this is about expedience - I would like to make an amendment to something that already exists, rather than rewrite - though yes another language might be the better ultimate route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to convert every `?+` to something that can't appear in the current record (e.g. the Record Separator), then do the `split()` on `+`, then convert it back:

```
exampleString="Var1, Var2Pt1+Var2Pt2+Var2Pt?+3+Var2Pt4, Var3"

awkOutput=`awk '
BEGIN{FS=",";}
{
    gsub(/\?\+/,RS)
    NUM_PARTS=split($2,SUBFIELDS,"+");
    for (i = 1; i<=NUM_PARTS; i++) {
        gsub(RS,"?+",SUBFIELDS[i])
        print SUBFIELDS[i]","
    }
}
' <<<"$exampleString"`

echo $awkOutput;
Var2Pt1, Var2Pt2, Var2Pt?+3, Var2Pt4,
```

If you really do want `?+` from the input to become `+` in the output, as shown in the example in your question, then obviously just change `gsub(RS,"?+",SUBFIELDS[i])` to `gsub(RS,"+",SUBFIELDS[i])`.

Comment: Thank you - I've marked this as the answer, but I should mention to get my desired output the second gsub would be `gsub(RS,"+",SUBFIELDS[i])`.

Comment: @paulfrith You're welcome. I already said that in the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, this type of escaping is typically handled by CSV parsers automatically. `awk` may not be the best choice for this task.

For example, in Python you could write

```
>>> import io, csv
>>> exampleString = "Var1, Var2Pt1+Var2Pt2+Var2Pt?+3+Var2Pt4, Var3"
>>> filelike = io.StringIO(exampleString.split(', ')[1])
>>> list(csv.reader(filelike, delimiter='+', escapechar='?'))
[['Var2Pt1', 'Var2Pt2', 'Var2Pt+3', 'Var2Pt4']]
```

Comment: That's very nice - I definitely will look at porting across when I have more time - the file being imported is very complex, and not actually csv (I just used that for my example) - but I can already see from what you have shown here that this might be a neater route for the future.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1 :

`gawk 5.2.1` is perfectly happy accepting `FS = "?+(+)"` due to their ***very*** unique interpretation of a `regex` comprised of nothing except 3 duplication meta-characters and one grouping parenthesis pair. That said, most other dialects of `ERE` don't treat this `regex` as valid at all, while `posix`'s official text discourages them :

> ```
>  Implementations are permitted to extend the language to allow 
>  these. Strictly Conforming applications cannot use such constructs.
> ```

In fact, `gawk` even accepted something ridiculous like this while returning the same expected output :

> ```
>  FS = "?++++++++++++++(+)+++++++++++++++++++"
> ```

========================

```
__='Var1, Var2Pt1+Var2Pt2+Var2Pt?+3+Var2Pt4, Var3'

printf '%s' "$__"
```

> 

```
Var1, Var2Pt1+Var2Pt2+Var2Pt?+3+Var2Pt4, Var3
```

> ```
> printf '%s' "$__" | 
>
> mawk 'gsub( ", |[+]", ",\f", $!(NF=NF)) + \
>       gsub(OFS, "+")'     FS='[?][+]' OFS='\61\277\761'
> ```

```
Var1,
     Var2Pt1,
             Var2Pt2,
                     Var2Pt+3,
                              Var2Pt4,
                                      Var3
```

> - `OFS` is a `UTF-8`-invalid byte sequence, which makes it a safe choice for a placeholder or sep.

```
 Fun trivia regarding the octals that form the `OFS` ::
```

- for the latter 2 bytes, each has an underlying decimal number that is prime (`191 | 241`).
- If directly interpreting all 3 octals as decimal numbers (i.e. `\277` —> `277-b10` ), each form a prime number (`61 | 277 | 761`).
- Collectively, it also forms a 6th prime number (`61277761`)
- but when horizontally digit reversed, it's simply `8^8`