# Use specific middleware in Express for all paths except a specific one

Tags: node.js, routes, express, middleware

I am using the Express framework in node.js with some middleware functions:

```
var app = express.createServer(options);
app.use(User.checkUser);
```

I can use the `.use` function with an additional parameter to use this middleware only on specific paths:

```
app.use('/userdata', User.checkUser);
```

Is it possible to use the path variable so that the middleware is used for all paths except a specific one, i.e. the root path?

I am thinking about something like this:

```
app.use('!/', User.checkUser);
```

So `User.checkUser` is always called except for the root path.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I would add checkUser middleware to all my paths, except homepage.

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/account', checkUser, routes.account);
```

or

```
app.all('*', checkUser);
    
function checkUser(req, res, next) {
  if ( req.path == '/') return next();

  //authenticate user
  next();
}
```

You could extend this to search for the req.path in an array of non-authenticated paths:

```
function checkUser(req, res, next) {
  const nonSecurePaths = ['/', '/about', '/contact'];
  if (nonSecurePaths.includes(req.path)) return next();

  //authenticate user
  next();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to allow all request to a specific path, but not the sub-paths? (i.e. '/', '/style.css', '/background.jpg', but not '/lists/' or '/titles')

Comment: your static assets should be served out of a static directory.

Comment: @chovy How do I specify regex paths in nonSecurePaths and it works

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking @la

Answer (score 18):

You can set the middleware on each route also.

```
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})
```

Answer (score 13):

Instead of directly registering `User.checkUser` as middleware, register a new helper function, say `checkUserFilter`, that gets called on every URL, but passed execution to userFiled` only on given URLs. Example:

```
var checkUserFilter = function(req, res, next) {
    if(req._parsedUrl.pathname === '/') {
        next();
    } else {
        User.checkUser(req, res, next);
    }
}

app.use(checkUserFilter);
```

In theory, you could provide regexp paths to `app.use`. For instance something like:

```
app.use(/^\/.+$/, checkUser);
```

Tried it on express 3.0.0rc5, but it doesn't work.

Maybe we could [open a new ticket](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/new) and suggest this as a feature?

Comment: I think this is only supported from v4.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```javascript
app.use(/^(\/.+|(?!\/).*)$/, function(req, resp, next){...
```

This pass any url apart from /. Unless, it works for me.

In general

```javascript
/^(\/path.+|(?!\/path).*)$/
```

(see [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex))

Hope this helps

Comment: Another example, just because '/' is a tough example when trying to read a regex:
`/^((?!\/foo$).*)$/`
as in
`app.use(/^((?!\/foo$).*)$/, express....`
Combined with info from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075550/2245874)

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use order of setting api and middleware. In your case it must be something like this.

```
 var app = express.createServer(options);
    
    // put every api that you want to not use checkUser here and before setting User.checkUser
    app.use("/", (req, res) => res.send("checkUser middleware is not called"));
    
    
    app.use(User.checkUser);
    
    // put every api that you want use checkUser
    app.use("/userdata", User.checkUser, (req, res) =>
      res.send("checkUser called!")
    );
```

This is a full example.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3002;

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("hi"));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("check user");
  next();
});

app.get("/checkedAPI", (req, res) => res.send("checkUser called"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this library called [express-unless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-unless)

Require authentication for every request unless the path is index.html.

```
app.use(requiresAuth.unless({
  path: [
    '/index.html',
    { url: '/', methods: ['GET', 'PUT']  }
  ]
}))
```

Path it could be a string, a regexp or an array of any of those. It also could be an array of object which is URL and methods key-pairs. If the request path or path and method match, the middleware will not run.

This library will surely help you.

Answer (score 2):

Thing that worked for me is to init single route you want before initializing for-all check, for example:

```
var app = express.createServer(options);

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.use(User.checkUser);
```

My personal example is this and works:

```
const app = express();

...

app.use('/api/flow', flowLimiter, flowRouter);

app.use(csurf({
    cookie: false,
}));

...
```

So `csurf` is applied an all routes except `api/flow` - where I use sendBeacon, so I couldn't apply headers with tokens to it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @chovy is the best.

Another solution is:

I was facing a similar problem. So what I did was to split the functions in the "routes" file into different files and export them separately. Likewise I imported them in the "server" file separately and called the middlewares for the respective routes. But I wouldn't recommend this on a large scale, I had a small project of less than 10 routes so I didn't mind doing it. For scaling I would go for chovy's method.