# Skipping a middleware in express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not looking for authorization of a particular request and so I did this.If the request path matches I want to skip the `auth.verifyToken` middleware.How can I do this.I tried using `return next()` but its not working.

```
 eventRouter.param('pin', (req, res, next, pin) => {
        let path = `/event/matchpin/${pin}`;
         if(req.path === path){
            //do something here so that directly executes the route
         }
         //else it executes the auth.verifyToken middleware
        next();
      });
    app.use('/user',auth.verifyToken,eventRouter);
```

Comment: You can add compare check in the middleware itself.
Can you post whole code?

Comment: I would just apply the middleware to all routes that need it and not on anything you don't at the router definition level rather than "globally" applying to the endpoint with `use`. See: [Use specific middleware in Express for all paths except a specific one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12924759/2313887)

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow I cannot because params is not accessible in the middleware

Comment: Fair option @NeilLunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**next()** is used to skip the middleware, you are just using it at the wrong place.

Try this code:

```
 eventRouter.param('pin', (req, res, next, pin) => {
        let path = `/event/matchpin/${pin}`;
         if(req.path === path){
            // Next will by pass this middleware
            next();
         }
         //else it executes the auth.verifyToken middleware

      });
    app.use('/user',auth.verifyToken,eventRouter);
```