# Apache Config - Exclude Location from Authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, location, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I have a web application that is being protected by a Shibboleth authentication module. My current config is as below

```
<Location /MyApp>
 AuthType shibboleth
 ShibUseHeaders On
 ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
 require shibboleth
</Location>
```

The **shibboleth** is an authentication module that provides SSO capability and the current flow directs the user to an *Identity Provider* for the user to enter the login credentials. I want to be able to open up a specific URL so that the URL gets bypassed by the authentication module. I tried the below but it doesn't seem to work and I get a blank page on loading the URL

*Method 1*

```
<Location /MyApp/Login.html>
  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all
  AuthType None
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

*Method 2*

```
<Location /MyApp/Login.html>
  AuthType shibboleth
  ShibRequestSetting requireSession 0
  require shibboleth
</Location>
```

I did some additional debugging and it appears that the problem is with additional files the **Login.html** loads - such as css, js etc. What is the correct way to configure this in Apache so that the Login.html can be bypassed from the authentication

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My comment towards the end regarding the exclusion of additional files being loaded by **Login.html** ended up being correct. I used the following format to exclude the files that were being loaded by the html file

```
<Location ~ "/MyApp/(Login.html|SessionTimeout.html|accessDenied.html|/badRequest.html|status|css/*|login/*|images/*|style/*|js/*|javascript/*|)">   
  Satisfy Any   
  Allow from all   
  AuthType None   
  Require all granted   
</Location>
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Apache 2.4 instead of 2.2, in order to exclude "/server-status", the following was enough:

```
<LocationMatch "^(?!/server-status)">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    <RequireAll>
        Require ssl
        Require user valid_user_name
    </RequireAll>
</LocationMatch>
```

Analyzing:

- `<LocationMatch "regex">` is [equivalent](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch) to `<Location ~ "regex">`.
- The regex [used](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/glossary.html#regex), is `pcre` (perl compatible regular expressions).
- `^(?!/server-status)` means:

  - `^`: "starts with"
  - `(?!)`: "[negative look ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex) (instead of positive `(?=)`)"