# Apache mellon authorization condition / whitelist

Tags: apache, saml, mellon

I have implemented mellon (SAML2) authorization for apache web server, which works fine. Now I need to exclude API folder (URL) from this authorization, because API has it's own auth mechanism.

The application is running on CodeIgniter, so the %{REQUEST_URI} is always /index.php, so I'm using %{QUERY_STRING} for the condition. I started with simple test, and it works great, for URLs beginning with api, there is no header set, for other URLs it is.

```
<Location />
<If "!%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /api/">
    Header set FOO "NOT API - Authorization will be required"
</If>
</Location>
```

[image]
[image]

But when I add SAML commands inside the condition, they are executed also for API calls (I'm redirected to /mellon/ with Internal server error). Other than API calls works as normal - I'm redirected to authentication page.

```
<Location />
<If "!%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /api/">
    Header set FOO "inside SAM request"
    MellonEnable auth
    MellonEndpointPath /mellon/
    MellonSPMetadataFile /home/mellon_metadata.xml
    MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /home/mellon_metadata.key
    MellonSPCertFile /home/mellon_metadata.cert
    MellonIdPMetadataFile /home/Entity_2023.xml
    AuthType Mellon
    Require valid-user
    MellonUser "UID"
</If>
</Location>
```

The question is - why are Mellon commands processed when the condition is not met?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Config - Exclude Location from Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146455/apache-config-exclude-location-from-authentication)

Comment: It does not, because all codeigniter router comes as /index.php regardles of the url. In other words, location will always be / or /index.php