# exclude an exact phrase in regex

Tags: regex

How can exclude an exact phrase?!

for example I want not to match this **inside a regex code**:

```
a sentence with hello phrase
```

but match this

```
a sentence with oehll phrase
```

at first I used this:

```
^([^hello]*)$
```

but the only problem it has is excluding the letters "h","e","l" and "o" (not the term "hello")!

I read many articles about this and used \b, (?!...) and (...) in any way I could suppose, but I can't!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to negate specific word in regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)

Comment: yes, but they do not work! perhaps lookahead and/or look behind is unavailable! What can I do?

Comment: @RuAlv, you can start by stating the regex flavor/language/tool being used. And why can't you just negate the result of matching `hello`? That's the best way.

Comment: what's flavor/language/tool ?!

Comment: I want to replace some strings by rereplacer component (in joomla), I don't think I can do so by it! (negate the matching of hello)

Comment: can you use 2 regexen? first use your general regex using a capture group to get the complete match, if any. next you test your match result with a second regex containing the forbidden pattern. iff that match succeeds, drop the candidate.

Comment: @RuAlv "flavor/language/tool" would be "C# 5.0" (language) or "Eclipse 4.2.2" (tool) or "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) 8.32" (flavour). Flavour is the most generic, and therefore what the most people can assist you with, but your language or tool may not comply with any standard flavour, meaning you would have to massage answers so that they work with your implementation's eccentricities.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following regular expression:

```
^.*((\W|^)hello(\W|$)){0}.*$
```

This is just a hack and this expression will unfortunately also exclude sentences with "hello" embedded inside other words. (For example, "sentence with**hello**out phrase")

Alternative: Use the following to detect sentences with the phrase you want:

```
^.*((\W|^)hello(\W|$)).*$
```

And then just delete the sentences containing that phrase.

Disclaimer: 
Also, this expression has been written assuming you are dealing with raw lines in a text file and not English sentences. If you want to work with actual sentences, I suggest you first tokenize your text into separate sentences and then test each sentence with a similar regular expression.