# Jenkins Gerrit trigger on all branches except master

Tags: regex, jenkins, gerrit

I have a build in Jenkins triggered by Gerrit I would like to trigger on all branches except `master`. What regex should I use for this?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/45. Also more comments here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7087. I don't understand enough to translate these comments into a solution, but if you could, it'd be great if you could type up an answer yourself for future users.

Comment: @acheong87 Unfortunately the solution you found only works if you are using the git plugin directly, I have the Choosing Strategy set to Gerrit Trigger so it will not work for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) worked for me:

```
^(?!.*master).*$
```

Should trigger on everything **except** master. Kudos to [this questions answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex).

Comment: If entering this in the branches specifier in Jenkins, don't forget to prepend `:` to tell Jenkins this is a regex.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

`^(master.+|(?!master).*)$`

This excludes **master** only. Not **master_joda**, for example.

It is also based on [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex).