# Disable github Webhook temporarly

Tags: git

I need to preventing from build the specific job on specific conditions, how i can do this?

Pushing to specific repository and push to git using git push --no-verify

git commit -m "check"
git push --no-verify

disable build job automatically when i push to specific branch in specific repo

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are pushing commit to repository which trigger CI job to build the application. I guess it is rather problem with your CI configuration. What CI tool do you use? Maybe turning build off for specific branch or for all branches apart from master / developer will resolve issue?

Comment: I need to prevent from build in specific branch in "x" repo with jenkins CI integration server but in jenkins i have not option to do this , i have only option to listen to the repo and this is the problem.

Comment: I think we have possible duplication here of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314632/how-to-exclude-git-branch-from-building-in-jenkins
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155249/jenkins-gerrit-trigger-on-all-branches-except-master/18709097#18709097

Comment: It’s not working with github webhook, why?

Comment: Similarly how I ignore from git webhooks when I using git push, have a way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

If you go into `webhook settings` on your repository, there should be an **Active** section where you can disable for as long as you like.
[image]