# Is it possible to invert a call to String's replaceAll method?

Tags: java, string, str-replace

For example...

```
String s = "abcxyzabcxyz";
s.replaceAll("xyz", "---");
```

This would normally give me `"abc---abc---"`. How would I get it to give me `"---xyz---xyz"` instead?

Comment: Well, my first shot would be `s.replaceAll("abc", "---")`, but I guess that's not what you're after, right?

Comment: How is it supposed to handle this: `String s = "abcwxyzabctuvwxyz";`, `s.replaceAll("xyz", "123");`

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult... [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll) takes a regular expression as the first argument

Comment: @Eypros I guess what he wants is some kind of "replace everything but `xyz` with `---`" instead of "replace `xyz` with `---`". Most probably the question could be rephrased to: Please tell me how to use a regular expression replace accordingly.

Comment: the question is incomplete

Comment: @AdrianNasui I find it perfectly comprehensible... In calls to `replaceAll` he specifies *what to replace*. He's looking for a way to specify *what to keep*. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Well, Throsten, it is comprehensible, but as you stated, you have to do some 'guessing' to start giving an answer. :). Just saying!

Comment: @AdrianNasui Well, the more often I read it the more clear it becomes. If I could I'd edit above comment to not contain the "I guess" part :-D

Comment: What's incomplete is the method of replacing the characters he does not want to keep. Here is how I understand the requirement: Every substring between "xyz", including edges, should be replaced with "---".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) accepts a regex, if I understood you correctly, you can use:

```
s.replaceAll("[^xyz]", "---")
```

Explanation:

`[^xyz]` means *any* character that's **not** one of "x", "y" or "z".

In order to negate "xyz" as a series, use:

```
^(?!.*xyz).*$
```

Comment: What if you have "xabcxyzaxbcxyz" it returns x---xyz-x--xyz. The regex should include the three letters in the same order and not any single appearance of them. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1240293/1656663) should be used to build the regex

Comment: That second regex `^(?!.*xyz).*$` replaces either the whole string or none of it. I think you want to use the accepted answer from @jesantana 's link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1240337/1969638

Answer (score 1):

You can use this...

```
s.replaceAll("[^xyz]", "-");
```

On a more formal Java approach, I would use the Pattern class, like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^xyz]");
s.replaceAll(p.pattern(), "-");
```

Comment: As Adrian Nasui said in a nother comment, this yields `abc---------abc---------`.

Comment: This has a problem in case the string is "xabcxyzaxbcxyz" returns x---xyz-x--xyz. The regex should include the three letters in the same order and not any single appearance of them

Comment: This would be the best approach as it would replace letters on a singular basis instead of as a group as others are assuming.