# Spring Request Mapping complication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have the following request mappings in my controllers, but when i hit `/united-states/georgia` it always goes to the method mapped with `{country/city}` even though . How to force it to go to the united-states method. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{country:united-states|canada}/{state}")
public String getCitites(@PathVariable String country,@PathVariable String state){
.....
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{country}/{city}")
public String getDetailsInCity(@PathVariable String country,@PathVariable String city){
.....
}
```

Comment: try to change the requestmapping of getCities in @RequestMapping(value = "/{country:united-states|canada}-{state}")

Comment: I can't change my URL pattern to be country-state. There are more complications in app if I do that.

Comment: Your mappings are going to collide; you need to have some way to disambiguate these, e.g. `/cities/{country}/{state}` and `/details/{country}/{city}`

Comment: Why does Spring not honor the regex mapping i have provided? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure @RequestMapping annotations support regex lookarounds but try excluding "united-states" and "canada" from the request mapping annotation for getDetailsInCity()

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{country:^(?!.*canada)(?!.*united-states).*$}/{city}")
public String getDetailsInCity(@PathVariable String country,@PathVariable String city){
.....
}
```

I got the regex from here: [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)

Comment: Although not a clean solution, this works. I will accept it as an answer if no other better answer pops up. Thanks.