# Regex that fail when there excessive whitespaces between words

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to make a regex in Java that does not match excessive whitespaces between words, and whitespaces at the beginning and end.

I have done this regex so far

```
^[\\S].*[\\S]$
```

That fail when there are whitespaces at the beginning and end of a line

But how about excessive whitespaces between words?

I want this line to fail:

```
"test    test"
```

But not this:

```
"test test"
```

I tried this:

```
^[\\S].*(?![\\s]{2,}).*[\\S]$
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you just trim the string before sending it to your method?

Comment: Do you want excessive whitepsace strings to fail, or do you want to trim the whitespace within lines so that it does not fail?

Comment: @willOEM The regex should fail when the String starts with whitespace/ends with whitespace/has 2 or more whitespaces between words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/2136936

I came up with the following regex, which is exactly what I wanted:

```
^[\\S](?!.*\\s{2,}).*[\\S]$
```

One thing I don't understand though, is why it doesn't work this way: `^[\\S].*(?!\\s{2,}).*[\\S]$`

Comment: Your second alternative does not work because it requires that at *at least one position* in the string there are not two whitespaces (`.*` outside of the negation), while the first one requires that nowhere are two whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

For failure case just check for:

```
\s{2,}
```

i.e. a whitespace 2 or more times. If there is a match then fail the verification.

Answer (score 0):

This should check before and after and more than two spaces

```
[^\s]([ ]{2,})[^\s]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex for it (assuming you do not want to match the empty string):

```
"^\\S++(\\s\\S++)*+$"
```

First a nonzero amount of non-whitespaces, and then multiple (possible zero) repetitions of a single whitespace followed by multiple (non-zero) non-whitespaces.

Instead of the non-backtracking `++` and `*+` operators you can also use (with same result) the normal `+` and `*` operators; note that the performance of the non-backtracking operators will be a lot better in case the string is long (several kilobytes).