# Regex to get URL parameter anywhere in URL

Tags: regex

While fully aware this is likely a duplicate, I simply cannot find a solution to this problem.

**How to get a parameter anywhere it exist in a URL?**

Consider these urls:
`https://any.domain.com/uri-slug/random-string/specific-slug/?version='2'`
`https://any.domain.com/uri-slug/random-string/specific-slug/?paramOne=1&version=2`
`https://any.domain.com/uri-slug/random-string/specific-slug/?paramOne=1&paramTwo=2&version=2`

I want to get `version=2` out of these URLs.

This Regex will return `true` if `version=2` starts the parameters, but not if it's after the first param.

```
https:\/\/(\w)+.domain.com\/(\w)+\/(\S)+\/specific-slug\/[?&]+(version=2)
```

How can I get `version=2` to return true if it's present anywhere in the parameters?

Comment: If the version no is fixed i.e 2. A literal regex `/version=2/` will return it if present in URL.

Comment: And why so complicated? [`version='?\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/bK9dX2/1) will do the same. Additionally, which language do you use? If it is always `version=2`, you do not need a regex at all, so what is your question, really?

Comment: @anubhava: OP said *anywhere* in the parameters, so I wonder if there's really a structure but we'll see.

Comment: Yes, I have to verify the entire domain up to that `specific-slug` (also where the second `\w` is will have to be verified as well). After specific slug I need to know when version=2 is present and when it isn't. This is for tracking via hotjar.

Comment: Also, yes there is a structure. Sometimes `version=2` will be the first param, other times it will be the last out of possibly four.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to allow for any character to appear 0 or more times (.*?) before looking for the [?&] one or more times. You also might need to account for the single quote characters. In your first string, which I did not include below.
The portion of the regex `(\w)+\/(\S)+` also will not match your "uri-slug" because it contains a dash (non-word) character.

`https:\/\/(\w)+.domain.com\/(\w)+\/(\S)+\/specific-slug\/.*?[?&]+(version=2)`

I'd suggest using a regex tester tool to get it exactly the way you want it. Something like https://regex101.com/ could work but there are many.

Comment: Ha, I've been on regex101 all day. I've tried everything but that `.*?` and that solved it. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind, is there a character that would mean not present? In other words, return true if `version=2` isn't present?

Comment: It may not be super specific but the carat character in brackets means "anything but these characters". [^abc] means anything but an a, b or c. version=2 not being present might mean you just don't get a regex match (since you're checking specifically for it)

Comment: Yeah i've tried `https:\/\/(\w)+.domain.com\/(\w)+\/(\S)+\/specific-slug\/.*?[?&]+([^version=2])` but it returns false both with and without the version parameter. Thanks so much for your help, regex is clearly a weak point for me.

Comment: With what you are trying to do, you should check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex

Answer (score 0):

Check if the String contains "Version=2" by simply using String.contains() method in java if you are using it as language for your code.