# Syntax highlighting for first word in line (grammar package for Atom)

Tags: regex, stata, atom-editor

I'm working on improving the existing grammar for Stata for use on Atom, the [language-stata](https://atom.io/packages/language-stata) package. Stata code follows a pattern: the first word in a line is a command and a comma separates options from the objects of the command. For example, to run a linear regression of y on x without a constant, you run:

```
regress y x, noconstant
```

A triple slash means that the command continues in the following line. Thus the previous code is equivalent to:

```
regress x /// COMMENTS
y, /// MORE COMMENTS
noconstant
```

I think that the grammar should highlight *every first word* of a line, *unless* the previous line contains a triple slash. In the two examples above, it should highlight the command `regress`, but it should not highlight the words `y` or `noconstant` in the second example. I imagine something like:

1. Start capturing at the beginning of a line;
2. Highlight the first word;
3. Continue capturing as long as lines contain a triple slash;
4. Stop when I find the end of a line without a triple slash.

I've tried a few things. For instance:

```
{
    name: 'comment.line.stata'
    match: '///.*'
}
{
    begin: '^\\s*(\\w+)'
    end: '(?<!///)$'
    beginCaptures:
        "1":
            name: 'support.function.stata'
}
```

This code highlights the first word of every line, whether or not a triple slash preceded it. On the other hand,

```
{
    name: 'comment.line.stata'
    match: '///.*'
}
{
    begin: '^\\s*(\\w+)'
    while: '///'
    beginCaptures:
        "1":
            name: 'support.function.stata'
}
```

highlights the first word of the document and nothing else.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to be more specific! How does it sound?

Comment: But it does not recognize any pattern if I use `regress y x, noconstant`.

Comment: I tried to clarify and simply the problem a bit. I removed the part about the comma. Does it seem clearer?

Comment: What do you want to highlight in the first example: `regress y x, noconstant`? Please try [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/vL4oW6/5), but it is not so smart:(

Comment: Your code inspired me to find a solution! I posted it below. I just had to generalize your code a bit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stata. Nice to see you got an answer finally. :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on comments by [ccf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741681/ccf) and [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex), I came up with something that seems to work:

```
{
    name: 'comment.line.stata'
    match: '///.*'
}
{
    begin: '^\\s*([a-zA-Z_]+)(.*)(///.*)$'
    beginCaptures:
        "1":
            name: 'support.function.stata'
    end: '^([^/]+|/($|[^/]|/($|[^/])))*$'
}
{
    captures:
        "1":
            name: 'support.function.stata'
    match: '^\\s*([a-zA-Z_]+)'
}
```