# Matching pattern using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have to match sequence like baab, sdds in the string and the sequence should not be inside the square brackets.
So far i have used the regular expression

```
/([a-z])([a-z])\2{1}\1{1}(?![^[]*])/
```

It is giving me the desired output but the above regular expression also matching the sequence like bbbb which is undesirable.
I am thinking of having something to compare capture group1 and capture group2 not be equal.So far i didn't find anything useful.

[Link for same](https://regexr.com/3jh9b)

Comment: Regular expressions are not that powerful

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1240275/5267751)?

Comment: (i.e., you can use negative lookahead to ensure the two groups are not equal)

Comment: Looks like you already know about negative lookahead, why can't you do this?

Comment: @user202729 No, it's not a duplicate, OP wants what the fourth bird suggested (looks like matching four-character palindromes except ones composed of four identical characters).

Comment: Please note that it would be better if you specify the language you're using. There is no standard for regular expressions and specifying the language is a way to attract the best answers

Comment: I am not using any specific language but using https://regexr.com/ to fiddle around, how php would be a choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could add a negative lookahead after group 1 `(?!\1)` to assert that what follows the first group is not the same as group 1.

[`([a-z])(?!\1)([a-z])\2\1(?![^[]*])`](https://regex101.com/r/Jqw6Pm/2)

If you don't want your match to be between square brackets, you could add a negative lookbehind [`(?<!\[)([a-z])(?!\1)([a-z])\2\1(?!])`](https://regex101.com/r/Jqw6Pm/3) to assert that your match does not start with `[`. (if your engine supports this).

Comment: the regex given in line 1 is does ignoring the match if inside square brackets. I was wondering if it is possible to ignore the match found in line if there also exist a match between square brackets

Comment: @ashofphoenix Not really sure what you mean, could you give an example?

Comment: Yes as you can see that in test input line 2 has the match inside as well as the outside of brackets https://regex101.com/r/Jqw6Pm/4 once i remove the pattern to ignore square brackets

Comment: @ashofphoenix For this scenario with new requirements, you could consider creating a new question with a detailed example and if possible the programming language.