# include one word and exclude another python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

**Background:** I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'text': ["paid", "paid and volunteer", "other phrase"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['text'].apply(str)
```

**Output**:

```
                   text
0                  paid
1    paid and volunteer
2          other phrase
```

**Goal:**

1) check each row to determine if `paid`  is present and return a boolean (return `True` if `paid` is anywhere in the text column and `False` if `paid` is not present. But I would like to exclude the word `volunteer`. If `volunteer` is present, the result should be `false`.

2) create a new column with the results

**Desired Output:**

```
                   text     result
0                  paid     true
1    paid and volunteer     false
2          other phrase     false
```

**Problem:** I am using the following code

`df['result'] = df['text'].astype(str).str.contains('paid')  #but not volunteer`

I checked [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex) and it shows how to exclude a word but I am not sure how to include in my code

**Question:**
How do I alter my code to achieve 1) and 2) of my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lambda`:

```
df['result'] = df['text'].apply(lambda row: True if ('paid' in row) and ('volunteer' not in row) else False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logical and to check for both conditions.

```
(df.text.str.contains('paid')) & (~df.text.str.contains('volunteer'))
Out[14]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: text, dtype: bool
```