# JAVA regex pattern if statement

Tags: java, regex, if-statement, expression

This is what i have already.

```
^[abceghj-prstw-z][a-np-z]$
```

I am trying to form regex pattern with these requirements:
First position can be any letter but d,f,i,q,u,v.
Second position can be any letter but o.
The first and second position can't be BG, GB, NK, KN, TN, NT, ZZ.

So for example string "ap" = true.

ao = false (because second position is o).

gb = false (because it cant be gb)

I am pretty new with regular expressions so any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please show some example input and whether it should match or not.

Comment: Yes some exemples are wlcm

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to form the correct regex, or are you wanting to know how to use this regex in Java. Please try to make your question more clear

Comment: `^(?!bg|gb|nk|kn|tn|nt|zz)[abceghj-prstw-z][a-np-z]$`

Comment: some *candy*: you can use `[a-z&&[^dfiqv]]` to match any character between 'a' and 'z' with 'd','f','i',q'','v' excluded (but not that sure if that is more readable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of negative lookahead to make the regex fail if those specific patterns exist:

```
^(?i)(?!(bg)|(gb)|(nk)|(kn)|(tn)|(nt)|(zz))[abceghj-prstw-z][a-np-z]$
```

`(?i)` makes it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/5684265) you may add negative lookahead to exclude forbidden symbols from the beginnig of your regex:

```
^(?!bg|gb|nk|kn|tn|nt|zz)[abceghj-prstw-z][a-np-z]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookaheads or negative lookbehinds if you don't want to check the exceptions (gb, ...) manually. Here's an example with a negative lookbehind:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[abceghj-prstw-z][a-np-z](?<!gb|bg|nk|kn|tn|nt|zz)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("ap", "apo", "AP", "GB", "gb", "gg");
for (String input : inputs) {
    System.out.println(input + " " + p.matcher(input).matches());
}
```

Prints:

```
ap true
apo false
AP true
GB false
gb false
gg true
```