# Find string between two patterns with an AND condition in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search

I would like identify the string of characters that is between two patterns (`lettre/` and " in example). In addition, the identified string should not correspond to a third pattern (`somth?other` in example).

Python 3.7 running on MAC OSX 10.13

```py
import re
strings = ['lettre/abc"','lettre/somth?other"','lettre/acc"','lettre/edf"de','lettre/nhy"','lettre/somth?other"']

res0_1 = re.search('lettre/.*?\"', strings[0])
res1_1 = re.search('lettre/.*?\"', strings[1])
print(res0_1)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='lettre/abc"'>
print(res1_1)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 19), match='lettre/somth?other"'>

res0_2 = re.search('lettre/(.*?\"&^[somth\?other])', strings[0])
res1_2 = re.search('lettre/(.*?\"&^[somth\?other])', strings[1])
print(res0_2)
None
print(res1_2)
None
```

I would like to get `res0_1` for `strings[0]` and `res1_2` for `strings[1]`.

Comment: What do you mean to say? That you do not want to get a match if there is `somth?other` to the right of `/`? Try `r'lettre/(?!somth\?other)[^"]*"'`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KepctJ/1).

Comment: This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it 
Try this:

```
import re
strings = ['lettre/abc"','lettre/somth?other"','lettre/acc"','lettre/edf"de','lettre/nhy"','lettre/somth?other"']

res0_1 = re.findall('lettre/(.*)\"', strings[0])
res1_2 = re.findall('lettre/(.*)\"', strings[1])
print(res0_1)
print(res1_2)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think below code can give you what you asked in the question.

```py
import re
strings = ['lettre/abc"','lettre/somth?other"','lettre/acc"','lettre/edf"de','lettre/nhy"','lettre/somth?other"']

for i in strings:
    if 'somth?other' not in i.split('/')[1]:
        print(i.split('/')[1].split('"')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to get a match if there is `somth?other` to the right of `/` you may use

```
r'lettre/(?!somth\?other)[^"]*"'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KepctJ/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `lettre/` - a literal substring
- `(?!somth\?other)` - no `somth?other` substring allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a double quotation mark.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this site instead of try and error.
https://regex101.com/

```
In [7]: import re 
   ...: strings = ['lettre/abc"','lettre/somth?other"','lett
   ...: re/acc"','lettre/edf"de','lettre/nhy"','lettre/somth
   ...: ?other"'] 
   ...:                                                     

In [8]: c = re.compile('(?=lettre/.*?\")(^((?!.*somth\?other
   ...: .*).)*$)')                                          

In [9]: for string in strings: 
   ...:     print(c.match(string)) 
   ...:                                                     
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='lettre/abc"'>
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='lettre/acc"'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='lettre/edf"de'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='lettre/nhy"'>
None
```