# RegEx to not to contain "--"

Tags: regex, repeat, subsequence, negate

I want to validate a string with alpha numeric values, but if the string contains `--` (double dash) anywhere in the string, it should be invalid.

**valid:**

- `apple123`
- `-apple-123`
- `app-le123`
- `a-p-p-l-e-1-2-3`

**invalid:**

- `--apple123`
- `app--le123`

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/1920590

The above old post have the answer `^(?!.*bar).*$` which does the negation, but it does not work for same character repetition like `--`.

Can anyone help me to figure out to modify the `^(?!.*bar).*$` to identify `--` as a string.

Comment: Of course [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/1920590) works for `--`: `^(?!.*--).*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*--)[\w-]+$
```

- `(?!.*--)` is a negative lookahead assertion that will fail the match if `--` appears anywhere in input.
- `[\w-]` matches a word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` or a hyphen

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM3ZpA/1)