# One line command that sets error code 1 if string in multi-line stdin, 0 if not

Tags: regex, systemd

When I run the command

```
nmcli --get-values TYPE connection show --active
```

I sometimes receive a list of values as follows

```
vpn
802-3-ethernet
tun
tun
```

But other times the `vpn` line is not present. (the order of the lines cannot be assumed)

I'm looking for a one-liner that will accept the output of that `nmcli` command (presumably via pipe/stdin?) and return an exit code of 1 when `vpn` is in that list and an exit code of 0 when `vpn` is not in that list.

#### What I've Tried

- Every combination of `grep` that I can think of.  `grep -v` will absolutely not work because it will always find a line that is not `vpn`. Other options to `grep` return data, but do not change the error code (that I can find).
- Every negation regex I can find or think of. Regexes in the form `^(?!vpn).*$` do not work because there will *always* be a line that does not say `vpn`.

#### Use Case

I am writing a systemd service to update my dynamic DNS. But I don't want to set my dynamic DNS while I'm on a VPN. I want to use systemd built-in abilities (as much as possible) to control it. So I want to use the systemd built-in `ExecStartPre=` (which fails the unit on exit code 1+) to control whether the service starts.

If you've got a way to run a service (or not) using systemd depending on whether a VPN is connected, I'll accept that in lieu of the above. But naive assumptions like "`tun0` active=VPN" are false for me. I have various `tun` connections active at any one time, for various reasons. So triggering on `sys-subsystem-net-devices-tun0.device` does not work.

#### What Doesn't Work

Most of the Google and SO results I find are for line-specific negation and do not address my use case where there will be multiple lines.  Or they return the values and do not set the error code.  I need error codes set.

- Line-based:  [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)
- Line-based:  [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just checking for existence of `vpn` in the output, count the number of occurences, then evaluate a conditional expression checking on the number of lines:

```sh
nmcli --get-values TYPE connection show --active | [ $(grep -c ^vpn) -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I've never even **heard of** piping into a conditional expression, much less into command substitution like that! Thank you!!!