# Inverse regex match on group in Python

Tags: python, regex

I see a lot of similarly worded questions, but I've had a strikingly difficult time coming up with the syntax for this.

Given a list of words, I want to print all the words that *do not* have special characters.

I have a regex which identifies words *with* special characters `\w*[\u00C0-\u01DA']\w*`. I've seen a lot of answers with fairly straightforward scenarios like a [simple word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex). However, I haven't been able to find anything that negates a group - I've seen several different sets of syntax to include the negative lookahead `?!`, but I haven't been able to come up with a syntax that works with it.

In my case given a string like: "should print nŌt thìs"

should print `should` and `print` but not the other two words. `re.findall("(\w*[\u00C0-\u01DA']\w*)", paragraph.text)` gives you the special characters - I just want to invert that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular case, you can simply specify the regular alphabet range in your search:

```
a = "should print nŌt thìs"
re.findall(r"(\b[A-Za-z]+\b)", a)
# ['should', 'print']
```

Of course you can add digits or anything else you want to match as well.

As for negative lookaheads, they use the syntax `(?!...)`, with `?` before `!`, and they must be in parentheses. To use one here, you can use:

```
r"\b(?!\w*[À-ǚ])\w*"
```

This:

- Checks for a word boundary `\b`, like a space or the start of the input string.
- Does the negative lookahead and stops the match if it finds any special character preceded by 0 or more word characters. You have to include the `\w*` because `(?![À-ǚ])` would only check for the special character being the first letter in the word.
- Finally, if it makes it past the lookahead, it matches any word characters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BsVZuW/1). Note in regex101.com you must specify Python flavor for `\b` to work properly with special characters.

There is a third option as well:

```
r"\b[^À-ǚ\s]*\b"
```

The middle part `[^À-ǚ\s]*` means match any character *other than* special characters or whitespace an unlimited number of times.

Comment: I don't think that first regex works because it matches things like `zhì` - it just matches the zh.

Comment: Another issue - wouldn't `r"\b(?!\w*[À-ǚ])\w*"` only work on Latin-based special characters?

Comment: Yes the first one should also be surrounded by `\b`. Fixed. And yes, by “special characters” I just mean the range you posted, `[\u00C0-\u01DA]`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a regex, but just a completely different idea you may not have had besides using regexes. I suppose it would be also much slower but I think it works:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud    
>>> [word for word in ['Cá', 'Lá', 'Aqui']\
    if any(['WITH' in ud.name(letter) for letter in word])]
['Cá', 'Lá']
```

Or use `... 'WITH' not in` to reverse.