# Regex matching pattern in multiple lines without specific word in the match

Tags: regex, regex-negation, multiline

I would like to match the following pattern in multiple lines

1. The pattern begins with "PAT_A"
2. The pattern ends with the first ";" after "PAT_A"
3. The pattern contains "PAT_B" between "PAT_A" and ";"
4. The pattern does not contain "NOT_MATCH_THIS" between "PAT_A" and ";"

For example, this should make a match

```
PAT_A_YYY(
  OK,
  PAT_B
);
```

And this should not make a match.

```
PAT_A_XXX(
  NOT_MATCH_THIS,
  PAT_B
);
```

I managed to fulfill the first three requirements with

```
(PAT_A[^;]*?)(\bPAT_B\b)([^;]*;)
```

where the groups are for extracting the different parts matched.

However, I did not succeed in excluding matches containing "NOT_MATCH_THIS".

I have checked the post "[How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)" about negative lookahead. However, it seems that the answer there matches the whole line instead of the pattern requirement described above. And I am not sure how I should incorporate the negative lookahead into my regex pattern.

Is there any way I could match with regex fulfilling all the four requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
^PAT_A[^;\n]*(?:\n(?![^\n;]*NOT_MATCH_THIS)[^;\n]*)*\n[^;\n]*PAT_B[^;]*;
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `PAT_A` Match literally
- `[^;\n]*` Optionally match any char except `;` or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group (to repeat as a whole)

  - `\n(?![^\n;]*NOT_MATCH_THIS)` Match a newline, and assert that the string does not contain `NOT_MATCH_THIS` and does not contain a `;` or a newline to stay on the same line
  - `[^;\n]*` If the previous assertion is true, match the whole line (no containing a `;`)
- `)*` Close the non capture group, and optionally repeat matching all lines
- `\n[^;\n]*` Match a newline, and any char except `;` or a newline
- `PAT_B[^;]*;` Then match PAT_B followed by any char except `;` followed by matching the `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Za9bBl/1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a RegEx interpreter handy, but you could try this:

```
(PAT_A[^;]*?(?!NOT_MATCH_THIS))(\bPAT_B\b)([^;]*;)
```

Or maybe:

```
(PAT_A[^;]*?(?!NOT_MATCH_THIS)[^;]*?)(\bPAT_B\b)([^;]*;)
```