# Regex replace characters of string starts with character and end with any of two characters

Tags: php, regex

Trying to match string that starts with `#1-9` *note:* `#` is followed by a number from `1 to 9`
and ends with `#1-9` ***(or not)***.

Full string : `"#1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text#2printing and typesetting industry"`

***Idea:***

is to replace `#1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text` with `<span class="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>`

and `#2printing and typesetting industry` with `<span class="two">printing and typesetting industry</span>`

so to replace `#1-9` with `<span class="number">` and append the ending tag `</span>` at the end of each.

***but:***

let's say if the string has only one string starting with `#1-9` like that :

`"#1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"` how could be putting `</span>` at the end to close the `<span>` tag.

i'm guessing maybe using the last `"` at the end of words to prepend the closing `</span>` tag before it, since no more `#1-9` to stop before it, but without losing or replacing the last `"` of the string.

so it becomes: `"<span class="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>"`

Regex i've tried : `(#[0-9])(.*?)(#|")` but this is only matching the first part `#1` of the string and ignoring the `#2` part *(see full string)*.

I will be using `php` to match and replace maybe using `preg_replace` just need to find a way to the regex part first.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
function convert($str) {
    static $numberNamesMap = [
        1 => 'one',
        2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three',
        4 => 'four',
        5 => 'five',
        6 => 'six',
        7 => 'seven',
        8 => 'eight',
        9 => 'nine',
    ];
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '~#([1-9])(((?!#[1-9]).)*)~',
        function($matches) use ($numberNamesMap) {
            $class = $numberNamesMap[$matches[1]];
            $htmlText = htmlentities($matches[2]);
            return "<span class=\"$class\">$htmlText</span>";
        },
        $str
    ); 
}
```

## References

- [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

## Examples

1. 

```php
echo convert('#1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text');
```

outputs:

```html
<span class="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
```

2. 

```php
echo convert('#1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text#2printing and typesetting industry');
```

outputs:

```html
<span class="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span><span class="two">printing and typesetting industry</span>
```

3. 

```php
echo convert('#1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text#0printing and typesetting industry');
```

outputs:

```html
<span class="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text#0printing and typesetting industry</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a [negative look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It's very powerful and will only match if the match inside does not match.

```
#([0-9])((?:(?!$|#[0-9]).)+)
```

This will look for #0-9 and end if another #0-9 occurs, or end of line. The negative look-ahead bit is this: `(?!$|#[0-9])`. It says only continue if it cannot match $ or #0-9. You have to process it for every character, so when you don't match it, match the next character with `.`, and match it all in a capture group.

Here's the railroad diagram:

[image]

Which was generated using [regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#%23%28%5B0-9%5D%29%28%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%24%7C%23%5B0-9%5D%29.%29%2B%29)

Comment: Good one sir, but it's exceeding the double quote at the end, needed it to stop before that double quote if that is possible. so i can have matches of ```#1-9``` with following text only, that will help me do replacements i mentioned.

Comment: @AmrSubZero I thought the "" were just for formatting. Will the string always contain "# at the beginning and end with a "?. Could you just remove the quotes?

Comment: The string will always be inside double quotes "#1test", so i will have matches with only ```#1-9``` with following text, then replace all those with only following text inside ```span``` tag like: ```<span>test</span>```

Comment: @AmrSubZero Then your best bet is to just remove the quotes prior to running preg_replace. You can get preg_match to properly match the pattern with quotes, but I don't know of an easy way to get preg_replace to see and replace the beginning and end quotes and also iterate all the instances of #0-9. So, yeah, just remove the quotes.

Comment: yep, removing quotes is a perfect trick to also extract what is needed to be replaced, clever! thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace_callback()` is the right tool for this job.  To avoid needing to manually declare a number mapping array, you can use the `NumberFormatter` class.  Using `sprintf()` in the callback body will help to separate data from the html and make maintenance easier.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tYPhU))

```
$string = '#1Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text#2printing and typesetting industry#0nothing#35That\'s a big one!';

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/#(\d+)((?:(?!#\d).)+)/',
         fn($m) => sprintf(
             '<span class="%s">%s</span>',
             (new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT))->format($m[1]),
             htmlentities($m[2])
         ),
         $string
     );
```

Output:

```
<span class="one">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span><span class="two">printing and typesetting industry</span><span class="zero">nothing</span><span class="thirty-five">That&#039;s a big one!</span>
```

Note that if your actual strings after the `#[number]` NEVER have `#` symbols in it you can DRAMATICALLY improve the regex performance by using a greedy negated character class as the second capture group. `#(\d+)([^#]+)`  This reduces the step count from 283 steps to just 16 steps on your sample string.

To be perfectly honest, even a lazy pattern like `#(\d+)(.+?(?=#\d|$))` will process the sample string in 213 steps.  Performance might not be a factor, so use whatever regex you are most comfortable reading.